# How to change this default background highlight color of eclipse ? Pic attached

Tags: android, eclipse, ubuntu

With eclipse + android plugin on ubuntu the highlight background color of intellisense is grey while text is white which makes reading the text difficult as can be seen in the pic .

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By simply changing ubuntu theme fixed the problem :)